# Display a div only if there is enough space, and hide it if there isn't

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a date column.  Each date looks like

> Wednesday, 08.06.2011

When the width of the browser window is too narrow, I want to only display the date without the day of the week to conserve horizontal space.  Like this

> 08.06.2011

An ideal solution would allow a markup like

```
<div class="weekday">Wednesday, </div><div class="date">08.06.2011</div>
```

and be entirely css-based without involving JavaScript.  But if that is not possible I could live with a JavaScript-based solution.

Answer (score 8):

You need some scripting here. CSS can't do action based on some element's property like width.
Just add simple javascript command in head of you script, e.g. in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1024) 
        $('body').addClass('too-narrow');
});
```

Then do rest in CSS.

EDIT:

**Actually there is CSS solution to this if you really want it.**

```css
.row { height: 30px; background: red; color: white; overflow: hidden; }
.row120 { width: 120px; }
.row200 { width: 200px; }
.row .other { height: 30px; float: left; }
.row .date,
.row .weekday { height: 30px; float: right; }
```

```html
<div class="row row120">
    <div class="other">Tilte</div>
    <div class="date">18.04.2010</div>
    <div class="weekday">Wednesday</div>
</div>
<div class="row row200">
    <div class="other">Tilte</div>
    <div class="date">18.04.2010</div>
    <div class="weekday">Wednesday</div>
</div>
```

You need to have set height for both row div and other/date/weekday divs. Set those two to be floated right and all other (earlier) fields to float left.
Worked for me on Chrome (showing Title 18.04.2010), not sure how others.

Comment: That is neeeearly perfect.  It would be perfect if the date was aligned to the left while the weekday is not visible.

Comment: As you see, they are both floated to right so the weekday is last child and will "fall down". If they both left floated they date will drop. So either go for right float or switch positions of them.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will require javascript.  Below is a modification to your HTML to include a container around your display.  THe container could have more in it, but for simplicity I am only going to show the date in it.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="daydisplay" class="weekday">
        Wednesday
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        08.06.2011
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use any javascript library to get the width of the viewport.  YUI and JQuery both have these functions, so since that is easy I am going to assume we have a variable called widthOfScreen which holds the width of the viewport.  I am also going to assume we have a variable called left which holds the number of pixels over from the left this display is located.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
containerWidth = container.clientWidth || container.scrollWidth;

if (containerWidth + x > widthOfScreen) {
   document.getElementById('daydisplay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: An ideal solution would not depend on a pre-set browser width, but instead let the day of the week disappear if the table would otherwise become so narrow that horizontal scrolling would be required to see all elements of a line.  I did not find a concise implementation of this, but if you go to amazon.com and change the width of your browser-window the number of "items to consider" and "items you've viewed" that are displayed horizontally adjust accordingly.  I would like a similiar behavior, but I only need it for one single div.

Comment: That is as simple as putting a function that listens for a the window resize, and then makes the adjustment.  I think it might be window.onresize or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query for narrow windows, then within it define the weekday class as display:none.

Answer (score 0):

You can "query" what the user has his resolution set to. As an example, look at this:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

I am not sure what "too small" means in your application, as it is dependent on a lot of things (size of font, etc), but if you can determine when the browser window size is too small, you can then set up the JavaScript to hide the div #weekday.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty ugly solution, but if you want to make entire words disappear, there's no better CSS technique than to use `overflow: hidden`.

I modified your markup a bit... maybe you can come up with something better, but hopefully this points you in the right direction for a pure CSS solution:

```
<div class="date">
    <span>08.06.2011</span>
    <span class="weekday">Wednesday</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden; }
span { float: right; }
span.weekday { 
    float: left;
    padding: 0 4px; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/EQTBa/

Comment: This will cut the div. Not hide it fully when too narrow.

Comment: Actualy this gave me idea when using with float as you see.

Comment: I guess I should post the CSS from my fiddle, that's essentially what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

flex is magic :

https://codepen.io/rwaness/pen/abZKXNj (4th case)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    height: 30px;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #bcbcbc;
}
.col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.col + .col {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.col.full {
    flex: 1;
}
.col.reverse {
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    align-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col full reverse">
        <span>Wednesday</span>
        <span>08.06.2011</span>
    </div>
</div>
```